# What is the sequence of recipe execution when defining multiple active recipes

Tags: openrewrite

In my init.gradle file, I have defined 2 active recipes.

```
    rewrite {
      activeRecipe("org.openrewrite.java.testing.mockito.Mockito1to4Migration", "com.myorg.openrewrite.Mockito1to4Migration")
    }
```

When running `gradle -I init.gradle rewriteRun`, it seems that the recipe `com.myorg.openrewrite.Mockito1to4Migration` is run first regardless of the position in the activeRecipe list.

Is the sequence random? How can I force that `com.myorg.openrewrite.Mockito1to4Migration` is run first.

Comment: Sorry to see this question was missed before; have you since found a way to make it work for yourself? The team is slightly more active on Slack, although there's now an integration to get notified about any new questions here as well.

Comment: No, I did not find a way up to now.

Answer (score 0):

A [change has been push just now](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-gradle-plugin/commit/6a03a0f77d7011134fa206868d0ded5f23224a5d) that preserves the order of active recipes. This change should end up in release 5.35.0+ of the Gradle plugin; with [5.34.0 released](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-gradle-plugin/releases/tag/v5.34.0) just a couple days ago, I would typically expect the next release in two to three weeks.

Until the next release becomes available, order can be maintained by having a single active recipe, which is a yaml recipe which declares each of the recipes you want to run in order.

Hope that helps!